# ¿Cómo evito que localhost me redirija a la misma página?

Tags: localhost, wamp, server

Tengo **WAMP**, cuando accedo a localhost o por la IP 127.. solo me accede a un único proyecto y me es imposible acceder al resto de proyectos guardados en la misma carpeta raíz `wamp/www/`.

Si quito el proyecto, solo me sale que no encuentra la página. He intentado buscando en los blogs de notas de la carpeta `Bin/apache/conf` pero no he encontrado nada y buscando por internet he encontrado ninguna solución a mi problema, ya que es difícil formular una búsqueda tan específica.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Como están organizados estos diferentes proyectos dentro de el directorio raíz del servicio web de wamp? Quiero decir, como podría wamp (apache, supongo) reconocer uno del otro en caso de una petición?

Comment: Y suena como que quieres utilizar múltiples dominios, pero eso requiere trabajo tanto en apache como en la resolución de nombres de tu equipo para que cuando vayas a ir a los dominios a, b y c las peticiones se vayan a tu equipo y no que se resuelvan con dns.... o quizás tener tu propio dns y meterle todos esos dominios.... lo cual ya suena como querer matar una mosca con una bazuka. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: Bienvenid@ a [es.so]. Por favor consulta [ask]. Debes tratar de mostrar lo que has intentado para que podamos ayudarte. Si por casualidad estás usando la distribución de wamp **Bitnami WampStack** puedes utilizar la guía [Create a Custom Php Aplication](https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/infrastructure/lamp/administration/create-custom-application-php/). Si usas otra distribución de Wamp, convendría que indiques cual usas para que otros puedan ofrecer sugerencias pertinentes.

Comment: Seguramente sea una solución más tonta, ya que por defecto, cuando entras en localhost, te permite abrir todos los archivos dentro de una determinada ruta de acceso, que suele ser "Wamp/www/". El problema es que por algún motivo, mi ordenador en vez de realizar está conexión y mostrar todos los archivos o carpetas dentro de www, me accede directamente a uno de los archivos. Sin dejar opción a acceder al resto o a MySQL. No tiene relación con las DNS ni nada de eso.

Answer (score 0):

Tras todo el día, he dado con la solución. Había una copia de un archivo index.php en la carpeta www. DreamWeaver genera esa copia por razones que no entiendo todavia, por eso al acceder a LocalHost, solamente me accedía a ese archivo ignorando el resto de archivos.

Por defecto, abre como página el primer archivo index que encuentra.

Comment: *Había una copia de un archivo index.php en la carpeta www*, *No entiendo muy bien como se ha producido*... es que al instalar wamp te pone ahí un index.php. Y si quieres acceder a cualquier otro proyecto, aun estando ahí ese index.php, no tienes más que navegar a localhost/NOMBRE_DE_LA_CARPETA_DEL_PROYECTO y ya evitas ese index